# plot changes not affecting all subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I have a function that plots running times, and cuts out sections of time during the offseason.

```
def plotTimes(data):
    x = data["x"]
    y = data["y"]
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, data["years"], sharey=True)
    for i in range(data['years']):
        axes[i].plot(x, y)
        if i < data['years'] - 1:
            axes[i].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        if i > 0:
            axes[i].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            axes[i].yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
        axes[i].set_xlim(data['boundaries'][i]['start'],data['boundaries'][i]['end'])
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('5k Time')
    plt.title(data['name'])
    plt.show()
```

This code generated an image like this:
[image]

- Why is my xtick rotation not applying to all of the axes?
- Why isn't the top label in the center?
- Why is the axis label on the left edge?

Comment: In short, `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` is applied to the active axes, which in this case belongs to the last subplot. Just move that line into the loop.

Comment: thanks. Had to add `plt.sca(axes[i])` to make it active.